# How to get coordinate data of objects in SolidWorks using API

Tags: vba, solidworks

I want to know how to access coordinates of different objects in the SolidWorks feature tree via the API which uses VBA. The problem for me personally is to find the correct statement to extract the positional data which varies depending on the selected object. My objects are described through their own coordinate system and an origin point.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just in case no one here can help you due to limited knowledge of SolidWorks, take some time to explore the forums found here: https://www.cadtutor.net/forum/forum/57-net-objectarx-amp-vba/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For components you can use the **.Transform2** property. This will return a MathTransform object which contains the transofmration matrix data for the component. You can access the data of the MathTransform object with the **.ArrayData** property. This will return a array of 16 doubles. The first 9 elements define the 3x3 rotation matrix and the next 3 elements define the translation component (the xyz origin point of the component). In the API help you can find detailed informations.

In the API help is an example for how to get the transforms of assembly components: http://help.solidworks.com/2019/English/api/sldworksapi/Get_Transforms_of_Assembly_Components_Example_VB.htm

> My objects are described through their own coordinate system and an origin point

If you are using the reference geometry "coordinate system" as custom origin, you can access the MathTransform via **.Transform** of its **CoordinateSystemFeatureData** object.

To get the CoordinateSystemFeatureData object you have to first get the **Feature** object of your coordinate system - then call **.GetDefinition**

Example:

```
Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim Part As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim boolstatus As Boolean
Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long

Sub main()

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks

Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
Part.ClearSelection2 True
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("FEATURE NAME OF COORDINATE SYSTEM", "COORDSYS", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)

Dim swSelMgr As SelectionMgr
Set swSelMgr = Part.SelectionManager

Dim swFeat As Feature
Set swFeat = swSelMgr.GetSelectedObject6(1, -1)

Dim swFeatData As CoordinateSystemFeatureData
Set swFeatData = swFeat.GetDefinition

End Sub
```